# How to change the default group id when certain condition occurs?

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, customer-group, onestepcheckout

How can I change the default group id when certain condition occurs?

For instance, the default group id is 1 which is **general**. But I have a new group which is 4 (memebership).

And I want to set the customer to this group when they are purchasing a club item, I have this code in `onepage/billing.phtml`

```
<?php if($orderHasWineClub === true):?>
    <?php Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerGroupId(4); //4 being the customer group id ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

after this,

```
<?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
                <li class="control">
                    <div class="form-group checkbox">
                        <label for="billing:create_account" class="required">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="billing[create_account]" id="billing:create_account" value="1" title="<?php echo  $this->__('Create your account for later use') ?>"<?php if($orderHasWineClub === true):?> class="required-entry"<?php endif;?>/>
                            <a href="#" class="button-cart-simple"><?php echo  $this->__('Create your account for later use') ?></a>
                        </label>
                    </div> 
                </li>

<!-- the code of setCustomerGroupId(4) -->
....
....
```

But I still get **general** as my customer group. so I think the code is not working.

Any idea?

I am suing IWD_OPC onestep checkout by they way.

Comment: are you want set  this group  to after order save or during checkout process

Answer (score 1):

You need set the customer group and save the user:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->setGroupId(4);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: actually i get an error `a:5:{i:0;s:26:"Customer email is required";i:1;s:4775:"#0 C:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Resource\Customer.php(76): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'Customer email ...')
`

Comment: Customer is loggedin? When you make: echo $customer->getId(); you obtain a number? If user not loggedin you can't set group before logged

Comment: yes the customer is not logged in. i want to let the customer to register on checkout and set a group for them depending what is in their order.

Comment: You can set a Magento's Registry Pattern to set global variable. http://alanstorm.com/magento_registry_singleton_tutorial. When your user not loggedin you set the registry, after registration get registri and set groupId and finally unregister the registry.

Answer (score 1):

Tealou,you code is work only for loggin customer....
else it not work

```
<?php if($orderHasWineClub === true && Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->isLoggedIn()):?>
        <?php $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->setGroupId(4);
$customer->save(); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

you need to this code at `community\IWD\Opc\controllers\JsonController.php function  saveBillingAction` in `if (isset($data['create_account']) && $data['create_account']==1){`

If you want for all type custome`r guest/register then need to more customization checkout`

**Most suitable resolution:** goto saveBillingAction

add below before $this->checkNewslatter(); at jsoncontroller.php

```
$orderHasWineClub==yourvalue;

          if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
                    if (isset($data['create_account']) && $data['create_account']==1){
                        if($orderHasWineClub === true):
                            $data['customer_group_id']=4;
                        endif;  
                    }else{
                        //used for guest customer
                    }
                }else{
                        if($orderHasWineClub === true):
                            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->setGroupId(4);
$customer->save();
                            $data['customer_group_id']=4;
                        endif;  

                }
```

Comment: thanks Amit. but how can I send the data of `$orderHasWineClub` into `public function saveBillingAction()`??

Comment: can you tell $orderHasWineClub some value then $orderHasWineClub=your value

Comment: yes I can. the problem is not about setting the value for `$orderHasWineClub` but how to send data into `saveBillingAction()`

Comment: and how and where to trigger `saveBillingAction()`?

Comment: you did not  need send value to $orderHasWineClub to saveBiiling

Comment: ok thanks. but I still get `general` as my customer group....

Comment: i will check....